# Unable to add a reference of NAV web service to a .NET application

Tags: microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to add a Service reference of a Nav Web Service to my .NET console application.

When i try to do this I am not able to add a reference and I get an error.

The error message is as follows:

> There was an error downloading '192.168.9.215/.../AlfFail$metadata'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to (re)compile all related objects in your NAV database.
Can you successfully connect to the System webservice?

```
http://YourNAVServiceTier:7047/{NAVInstance-DynamicsNAV}/WS/SystemService
```